# Trapezoidal rule for system of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

I studied the trapezoidal rule for first-order differential equations. If the
problem is
$$y' = f(t, y)$$
the rule is given by the recursive formula
$$y_{n + 1} = y_n + \frac12h(f(t_n, y_n) + f(t_{n + 1}, y_{n + 1}))$$

I came across the following exercise, which I don't know how to solve:

> Apply the trapezoidal rule to the problem
>   $$\begin{cases}
> x''(t) = -\frac{x(t)}{r^3} & x(0) = 0.5, x'(0) = 0\\
> y''(t) = -\frac{y(t)}{r^3} & y(0) = 0, y'(0) = 0
> \end{cases}$$
>   where $r = \sqrt{x(t)^2 + y(t)^2}$. In particular, obtain the recursive formula
>   that defines the consecutive approximations $\{x_n, y_n\}$ of $\{x(t_n),
> y(t_n)\}$.

First of all, since it's not a first-order equation I converted the problem
into a system of $4$ equations and $4$ initial conditions, but now I don't know
how to proceed because $x$ and $y$ are connected since there's that $r$ factor.
Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resulting problem would be:
$$\left\{\begin{align*}
\dot{x}&=u\\
\dot{y}&=v\\
\dot{u}&=-x/r^3\\
\dot{v}&=-y/r^3
\end{align*}\right.$$
with $u(0) = v(0) =y(0)= 0$ and $x(0) = 0.5$

Now you have with $\vec{w} = (x, y, u, v)^{T}$ and $\vec{f}=(u,v,-x/r^3,-y/r^3)^{T}$the following system:
$$\frac{d\vec{w}}{dt} = \vec{f}(\vec{w})\tag{*}$$
Simply apply your integration rule to $(*)$. Since your numerical method is implicit, and $\vec{f}$ is non linear in $\vec{w}$, you will need some iterative solver to obtain the $\vec{w}^{n+1}$ vector solution.

Going further, permit me to apply the method to $(*)$. The resulting numerical scheme is:
$$\vec{w}^{n+1}=\vec{w}^n+\frac{h}{2}\left(\vec{f}(\vec{w}^{n})+\vec{f}(\vec{w}^{n+1})\right)$$
The term $\vec{f}$ this time does not depend explicitly on time $t$.

Comment: Wow, your answer is very extensive and you've been so quick! I see now that the $r$ factor was not a problem, I was simply confused. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It saddens me to see that you have posted three well-posed questions and no one responded. Unfortunately they are too advanced for me, otherwise I would have attempted to answer.

Comment: You are welcome @rubik. Don't worry about that! Thank you for your effort! Good luck!